# Where can I see how many relics another empire has?

Tags: stellaris

I have seen notifications that other empires have relics. Thanks to a tech advantage I have a decent level of intel on most other empires; in the espionage screen it says I have "High" intel about their governments, and explicitly lists "Number of Relics Owned" as one of the pieces of information available to me. Where in the UI can I find this information?

Comment: I do not think this is possible at the moment

Answer (score 2):

##### While this is not the information suggested in the tooltip and not reliant on intel, this is a way to figure out how many relics an empire has.

You can see relic score on the victory screen.

Unfortunately the relic score is different for each relic, so it won't give you an exact number with full certainty.

The score for each relic can be [found in the wiki.](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Relics)

There are some options to limit the potential combinations:

- The Galatron (20000 score) gives all other empires a wargoal which makes it easy to spot.
- There will be at most one Precursor relic worth 5000 score (and if you know where the homeworld is, you'll know who most likely holds the relic).
- You'll probably also know who defeated the crisis, making these relics (5000 score) easy to spot as well.

That leaves the following relics:

| Relic | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Surveyor | 200 |
| Head of Zarqlan | 200 |
| Blade of the Huntress | 200 |
| Omnicodex | 500 |
| Rubricator | 1000 |
| Scales of the Worm | 1000 |
| Defragmentor | 1000 |
| Ether Drake Trophy | 1000 |
| Vacuum Flower | 1000 |
| Miniature Galaxy | 2000 |
| Khan's Throne | 3000 |
| Maw of the Toxic Entity | 3000 |
| Crystal of Odryskia | 3000 |

The possible combinations lead to the following conclusions (**assuming it has none of the special relics listed above**, if it does, substract that value):

- If the empire has a relic score of **0**, it has **no** relics
- If the empire has a relic score of **200**, it has **one** of the first three relics
- If the empire has a relic score of **400**, it has **two** of the first three relics
- If the empire has a relic score of **500**, it has the **Omnicodex**
- If the empire has a relic score of **600**, it has **three** of the first three relics
- If the empire has a relic score of **700**, it has the **Omnicodex and one** of the first three relics
- If the empire has a relic score of **900**, it has the **Omnicodex and two** of the first three relics
- If the empire has a relic score of **1100**, it has the **Omnicodex and three** of the first three relics

All other possible combinations can be made from one of the above plus some thousands. There, the combinations become more complicated, you'll just have to calculate the possibilities.

Keep in mind that one empire can have a maximum of 8 relics and you can still check the prerequisites for a lot of them (if the Ether Drake is still around or the Khan hasn't been defeated, no one will have the corresponding relic).